# Is it okay to connect through 4-5 tables regularly?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database where I have to query/join 5 tables in succession to get a URL which will be pushed onto the site.

1. Get active version of flow
2. Get key of backend flow of version
3. Get key of backend flow flow
4. Get key of backend page
5. Get url of next page

This was the result of an attempt to have a "plug and play" solution to testing new flows on our site.

I expect under our peak traffic times this sequence will happen about 200 times a minute (it needs to happen twice per page).

Is this okay? Should I expect considerable performance drawbacks due to this implementation? Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: You are going to have to tell us a bit more, specific information. It is likely that this can be reduced to one query, but only if we know something about the schema for these tables

Comment: Does it work at 100 times per minute? If so, sure, you're fine. If not, start finding out why. If this query only takes a few milliseconds to complete there's really no way that can impact your application. If it takes longer than a few seconds then you're in trouble.

Comment: Instead of querying tables in succession, try to combine them into a join.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here's a link to the database structure https://app.sqldbm.com/MySQL/Share/4Br0S-Ok57ZXt7uDuoX44UGFrngIE8md_DYjF4jNYw0

Basically on a given page the Funnel_ID will be in the URL as a query parameter. Then I have to update a link on the page for the next two backend pages.

Comment: @Barmar I intend on doing that, wouldn't 4-5 Joins still have a significant performance impact?

Comment: It depends on whether the joining columns are indexed. It's still usually better than doing the queries sequentially, since there's much less per-query overhead.

Comment: @barmar I believe they are indexed, let's say this event happens twice per page, if I'm getting 100 pageviews/minute this is happening about 4 times per second. Does that sound like I'm within a safe enough margin? I don't know much about what type of load your average MySQL servers can handle.

Comment: It depends on the hardware configuration of your database server, there's no such thing as an "average" server.

Comment: If it can't keep up, you'll need to get faster hardware, or use a cluster. And if the data doesn't change frequently you can use caching.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a way to stress-test the server to find out?

Comment: Google "stress test mysql" and you'll find a number of tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are projecting a thousand queries per *second*, then we need to discuss things.  For a mere few hundred per *minute*, there should be no problem.

Those 5 steps sound like 5 `SELECTs` where one builds on what the previous one did.  Please learn about `JOINs` and subqueries.  You can probably write a *single query* that does the entire task.  Now you might be below 100/minute.

How many rows do you have?  A thousand?  No problem.  A million?  It depends.

Indexes are your friend in performance.  If you do have a performance problem, then the solution may be as simple as adding a composite index.  If you get to this point, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`